# Changing the value of a static integer of a class from another class by making the object of the first class. Is it possible in Java?

Tags: java, class

Let us take an example:

```
class A {
  public static int a=0
    void sampleFunction () {
    //some code which always runs
    a++;
    }
}
```

and we have another class:

```
class B {
   A object=new A();
   void sample () {
      //now we have some conditions
      if(condition 1) {
         object.sampleFunction();
         //value of a increases each time the function is called
       }
      else if(condition 2) {
         object.a=0;
       }
    }
}
```

My question is, suppose sample function is called 5 times, hence the value of a is 5. Now, condition 2 is satisfied. 
Again, we have condition 1 being satisfied, so sample function is called again. Would the new value of a be 6 or 1?

Comment: `1` of course (I believe what you mean is, when condition 2 is satisfied, at that moment, condition 1 is not satisfied, right?)... anyway shouldn't it be something that you can easily test out by yourself?

Comment: You don't need an instance of the A class to update the static variable

Comment: `A.sampleFunction()` should be static if that's all it does.

Comment: You need to understand what a static variable is and how it can be used

Comment: @noone Edits should not be used to suggest answers or provide comments. If you have an answer or comment, post it.

Comment: @noone Stop vandalizing this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is 1.

Because as defined in your pseudo code, the clause in condition 2 would have set the value for static variable **a** in object (class A) to 0.

Not sure what the real intention of this question was but if you are
trying to understand what static variable is, have a look at the [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html):

> Sometimes, you want to have variables that are common to all objects.
>   This is accomplished with the static modifier. Fields that have the
>   static modifier in their declaration are called static fields or class
>   variables. They are associated with the class, rather than with any
>   object. Every instance of the class shares a class variable, which is
>   in one fixed location in memory. Any object can change the value of a
>   class variable, but class variables can also be manipulated without
>   creating an instance of the class.

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Comment: Accidentally removed your edit. Can you please re-modify what I had done wrong?